# \chemfig{} pentagon is tilted slightly, need the bottom of pentagon to be flat

Tags: chemfig

When I try and write the following command `\chemfig{*5(-----)}` It gives me a slightly tilted pentagon. I need one whose base line is parallel to my line of page. Like the one shown below.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the `chemfig` manual section 10 *Rings* subsection 10.2 *Angular position*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{*5(-----)}
\chemfig{[:18]*5(-----)}
\end{document}
```

[image]